# SpringSecurity AuthorizationFilter returning 403-Access Denied with user logged in

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-security, jwt

I am using JWT for keeping the user authenticated between requests. The thing is that, after registering and logging successfully, building the token used for the rest of the requests, when I try to make a request which is not behind a ".permitAll()" the authorizationFilter says it denies the access when checking the authorization, even when the user logged has the authorities demanded

Those are the console logs with the error:

```
2023-09-26T18:23:25.241Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JWTAuthenticationFilter (6/13)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.250Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.g.g.i.JWTAuthenticationFilter          : USUARIO: george
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.252Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.g.g.i.JWTAuthenticationFilter          : AUTORIDADES: [ROLE_USER]
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.252Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.253Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (7/13)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.253Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Did not process authentication request since failed to find username and password in Basic Authorization header        
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.253Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.253Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.253Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.253Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (11/13)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.254Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.spring
framework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=george, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED],
 Authenticated=false, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=192.168.48.1, SessionId=03662B9D807EE64CDC7E8E6EE96F0FC7], Granted Authorities=[]]
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.254Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.254Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from 03662B9D807EE64CDC7E8E6EE96F0FC7
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.255Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.255Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.255Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$Header
WriterRequest@7a0e32f2]
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.255Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWrite
rFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@7a0e32f2] using AuthorityAuthorizationManager[authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.256Z TRACE 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=geo
rge, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails
 [RemoteIpAddress=192.168.48.1, SessionId=03662B9D807EE64CDC7E8E6EE96F0FC7], Granted Authorities=[]] to access denied handler since access is denied
backend  | 
backend  | org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at com.gametags.gametags.infrastructure.JWTAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:41) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:78) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:67) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar!/:na]
backend  |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
backend  | 
backend  | 2023-09-26T18:23:25.258Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
```

This is my SecurityConfig filterchain:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    /*return http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
          auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        }).formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .build();*/
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
//        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
//        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).permitAll()
//            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/classification/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
  }
```

This is my login method:

```
public AuthResponseDTO loginUser(LoginInput input) {
    User user = userService.findOneUserByUsername(input.getUserName());
    if(ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(user)){
      Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
              .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(input.getUserName(), input.getPassword(), List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))));
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
      log.info("User logged" + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
      String token = jwtGenerator.generateToken(authentication);
      return new AuthResponseDTO(token);
    }else{
      throw new NoSuchElementException("The user doesn't exist");
    }
  }
```

This is my JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
@Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String token = getJWTFromRequest(request);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    if(StringUtils.hasText(token) && tokenGenerator.validateToken(token)){
      String username = tokenGenerator.getUsernameFromJWT(token);
      logger.info("USUARIO: " + username);
      UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
      logger.info("AUTORIDADES: " + userDetails.getAuthorities().toString());
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities());
      authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
      session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
  }
```

This is my register method:

```
public User registerUser(RegisterInput input) throws Exception {
    if (!Objects.isNull(userService.findOneUserByUsername(input.getUserName()).getId())) {
      throw new Exception("User already existing");
    }
    return userService.createUser(User.builder()
        .id(UUID.randomUUID())
        .password(input.getPassword())
        .username(input.getUserName())
        .country(input.getCountry())
        .roles(List.of("ROLE_USER"))
        .build());
  }
```

The version Im using of SpringBoot is 3.0.5 and SpringSecurity is 2.3.3

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried changing hasAuthority to hasRole and changing the roles to USER instead of ROLE_USER and nothing has worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` constructor you used doesn't allow to pass authorities. There is another one with a third parameter for authorities (a list of `GrantedAuthority` you can use `SimpleGrantedAuthority` as implementation) see the documentation here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html#UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-

Since you aren't passing user authorities correctly, Spring sees an authenticated user without roles.

So you should convert authorities from a list of strings to a list of GrantedAuthority and then pass it as a third constructor parameter. You can use the password as a second parameter.

Comment: Yes, I had to change the constructor in the JWTAuthenticationFilter to use the password as a second parameter instead of the authorities and the authorities as the third parameter